# UPDATE an ORDER BY query with an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array, which contains numbers. And there is a table, whith two columns: `id` and `num`.

For example the array is: `(2, 7, 1, 0)`

And I would like to order the table by the id (`ORDER BY ID DESC`), and UPDATE the `num` values in this order, with the array elements.

So the first elements `num` value in the order, should be 2, the second 7, etc...

Is it possible using mySQL only, or I have to manage it in PHP?

---

Example:

Table:

```
id | num
--------
 1 | 0
 5 | 0
 6 | 0
 11| 0
```

Array: `(5, 9, 10, -20)`

Table after the query:

```
id | num
--------
 1 | 5
 5 | 9
 6 | 10
 11|-20
```

Comment: This seems to be possible with Mysql, so you wanna update these records based on the array given there in one query? Or what are you looking for exactly.

Comment: I would like to update the records num column from the array elements, based on the position of the record in the ordered result

Comment: but how to set the nth records `num` value to the arrays nth element?

Comment: your question is not clear. add samples of source data and expected result, and query you have so far please

Comment: You should just do this in php and issue update queries for each row. Anything done in mysql would be really "hacky" and prone to issues. Mysql doesn't really have a built in rownum. If it did, you could likely use [elt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) to find the item in a list of numbers. Without rownum, you would likely have to use a temporary table or create a massive case statement with each id/number combination. Unless you had several hundred updates you wouldn't likely notice a problem with the updates.

Comment: If you did have a lot, then you would be best off using a temporary table where you query all the ids and insert into another table the id/new number mapping (one query can likely insert all the rows) and then issue one update query to set the number value in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @a=0;
UPDATE table1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT @a:=@a+1 as i,
    id
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY id
) as t
ON table1.id = t.id
SET table1.num= ELT(t.i, 5, 9, 10, -20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is better you update row by row using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple words you can do something like this:

```
$array = array(5,9,10 -20);
$i = 0;
$q = 'select id from `table` order by id desc limit ' . count($array);
// use some sql magic here - PDO or mysqli to get results
while ($row = $sql_result->fetch()) {
    $new_value = $array[$i];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $q = 'update `table` set `num` = ' . $new_value . ' where `id` = ' . $id;
    // more sql magic here. with prepared statements etc
    $i++;
    // and increase $i to get next array value
}
```